# Unity: Make camera only follow the player in x-direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using the following script, and it makes the camera follow the player (in both x and y direction):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Camera2DFollow : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform target;
    public float damping = 1;
    public float lookAheadFactor = 3;
    public float lookAheadReturnSpeed = 0.5f;
    public float lookAheadMoveThreshold = 0.1f;

    float offsetZ;
    Vector3 lastTargetPosition;
    Vector3 currentVelocity;
    Vector3 lookAheadPos;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        lastTargetPosition = target.position;
        offsetZ = (transform.position - target.position).z;
        transform.parent = null;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        // only update lookahead pos if accelerating or changed direction
        float xMoveDelta = (target.position - lastTargetPosition).x;

        bool updateLookAheadTarget = Mathf.Abs(xMoveDelta) > lookAheadMoveThreshold;

        if (updateLookAheadTarget) {
            lookAheadPos = lookAheadFactor * Vector3.right * Mathf.Sign(xMoveDelta);
        } else {
            lookAheadPos = Vector3.MoveTowards(lookAheadPos, Vector3.zero, Time.deltaTime * lookAheadReturnSpeed);  
        }

        Vector3 aheadTargetPos = target.position + lookAheadPos + Vector3.forward * offsetZ;
        Vector3 newPos = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, aheadTargetPos, ref currentVelocity, damping);

        transform.position = newPos;

        lastTargetPosition = target.position;       
    }
}
```

However, I only want it to follow the player in the x-direction. Been playing around with the script for a while, but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That appears to be the script provided in the Sample Assets, which may more complicated than what you need.

I've achieved what you're trying to do before by simply using the following:

```
void Update () {
    transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed);
}
```

This is from a script attached to the main camera.